# Delete all Product Line Items for an Opportunity, Invalid left hand side in assignment error

Tags: invalid

I am trying to delete all Product Line Items for the "current" Opportunity from a custom button on the Opportunity object.

This code gives me an Invalid left hand side in assignment error

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/apex.js")}
var record = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
record.Id = '{!Opportunity.Id}';

List<OpportunityLineItem> olis = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
olis = [Select Id From OpportunityLineItem Where OpportunityId ='Record.ID'];
if(olis.size()>0) delete olis;

sforce.connection.update([record]);
window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing Apex and JavaScript... This won't work. Instead, you need to use something like:

```
var lineItems = sforce.connection.query("select id from opportunitylineitem where opportunityid = '{!Opportunity.Id}'")
var oliIds = []
var qri = new sforce.QueryResultIterator(lineItems)
while(qri.hasNext())
    oliIds.push(qri.next().Id)
sforce.connection.deleteIds(oliIds)
```

You'll want to read the [AJAX Toolkit Developer's Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/) developer's guide for more information.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox,  Should this run as posted? I'm getting lineitems,records forEach is not a function

Comment: @Stavros I was mobile, so I didn't have a chance to get the proper syntax down, but the newly edited version should work for you.

Comment: This worked like a charm!
Impressive that you can do that on your phone. I've been working on this nonstop since Saturday and couldn't have gotten here without your help.
Thank you

Comment: @Stavros Most of my answers are not from my phone, to be sure, but short answers like this aren't that bad. I'm glad you were able to get where you wanted.